# Trouble With the 'pivot_longer' Function

Tags: r, pivot

I am trying to turn a wide set of data (a table), into a long set using the `pivot_long`function but it is failing on account of the error message:

> Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") :
> no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

Here is the code I have been using:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

n= 8

dm<- 300/1000 #max diameter (mm)
am<- (dm^2*pi)/4 #ergo max area (m^2)
qm<- 800/3600 #max flow rate (m^3/h)

i<- am/n
ii<- qm/(am/i)

A<- seq(from = (0+i), to = am, by = i)
Q<- seq(from = (0+ii),to = qm, by = ii)

u<- sapply(Q,'/',A)
colnames(u) = c(A)
rownames(u) = c(Q)

u %>% 
pivot_longer(c(u[1:8]), names_to = "Area (m^2)", values_to = "Flow Rates (m^3/h)")
```

Comment: `u` does not seem to be a `data.frame/tibble`, `pivot_longer` expects a a data frame to pivot.

Comment: I have succesfully transformed u from a numeric value to a dataframe, but unfortunatly the pivot_longer function now does not work on account of a new error message: 'Error in `pivot_longer()`:
! Can't subset columns with `u`.
✖ Subscript `u` must be a simple vector, not a matrix.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First argument of `pivot_longer` is `cols` which should be column(s) to pivot into longer format. So, I have created a rowid which was used for pivot_longer. You can use the following code:

```
rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")  
graphics.off()
library(rayshader)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

n= 8

dm<- 300/1000 #max diameter (mm)
am<- (dm^2*pi)/4 #ergo max area (m^2)
qm<- 800/3600 #max flow rate (m^3/h)

i <- am/n
ii <- qm/(am/i)

A <- seq(from = (0+i), to = am, by = i)
Q <- seq(from = (0+ii),to = qm, by = ii)

u <- sapply(Q,'/',A)
colnames(u) = c(A)
rownames(u) = c(Q)

as.data.frame(u) %>% 
  rowid_to_column(var = "rowid") %>% 
  pivot_longer(col = -c(rowid), names_to = "Area (m^2)", values_to = "Flow Rates (m^3/h)")
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you very much, but as a final point, I would like the very far left column, the one descending from the value of 0.02777... to be in the column of the pivoted data frame that your code fills with the 'rowid' values. If this is this possible how might you going about achieving it?

Answer (score 0):

When peeking for some context from [follow-up Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76686825/supplying-discrete-values-to-a-continous-scale), it looks more like a task for `expand.grid` / `tidyr::expand_grid()` :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

n  <- 8
dm <- 300/1000    # max diameter (mm)
am <- (dm^2*pi)/4 # ergo max area (m^2)
qm <- 800/3600    # max flow rate (m^3/h)

i  <- am/n
ii <- qm/(am/i)

expand_grid(
  Area = seq(from = i, to = am, by = i),
  Flow = seq(from = ii,to = qm, by = ii)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Velocity = Flow / Area)
#> # A tibble: 64 × 3
#>       Area   Flow Velocity
#>      <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 0.00884 0.0278     3.14
#>  2 0.00884 0.0556     6.29
#>  3 0.00884 0.0833     9.43
#>  4 0.00884 0.111     12.6 
#>  5 0.00884 0.139     15.7 
#>  6 0.00884 0.167     18.9 
#>  7 0.00884 0.194     22.0 
#>  8 0.00884 0.222     25.2 
#>  9 0.0177  0.0278     1.57
#> 10 0.0177  0.0556     3.14
#> # ℹ 54 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>