# Supplying Discrete Values to a Continous Scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a contour map showing how velocity through a pipe changes with diameter and flow rate, but keep being told that I'm supplying discrete value to the continuous scale. I'm unsure exactly what this means. Here is the code I'm using:

```
cat("\014")  
graphics.off()
library(rayshader)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

n= 8

dm<- 300/1000 #max diameter (mm)
am<- (dm^2*pi)/4 #ergo max area (m^2)
qm<- 800/3600 #max flow rate (m^3/h)

i<- am/n
ii<- qm/(am/i)

A<- seq(from = (0+i), to = am, by = i)
Q<- seq(from = (0+ii),to = qm, by = ii)

u<- sapply(Q,'/',A)
uu<- u
colnames(uu) = c(A)
rownames(uu) = c(Q)


U<- as.data.frame(uu) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "Flow") %>% 
  pivot_longer(col = -c(Flow),names_to = "Area", values_to = "Velocity")

g2<- U %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Flow, y=Area, fill=Velocity))+
  geom_tile()+
  geom_contour(aes(z=Velocity),colour="black")+
  scale_x_continuous("Flow", expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_continuous("Area", expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_fill_gradientn("Velocity",colours=terrain.colors(10))+
  coord_fixed()

#rayshader
g2 %>% 
  plot_gg(
    multicore = TRUE,
    raytrace = TRUE,
    width = 7,
    height = 4,
    scale = 300,
    windowsize = c(1400,866),
    zoom = 0.6,
    phi = 30,
    theta = 30
  )
```

In specifying the parameters: "Flow", and "Rate", I'm trying use columns in the data frame "U" as my x and y axes, but this doesnt seem to be working. I though perhaps they must have to be numeric value instead, which I tried but again to no avail.

Comment: Flow and Rate do have to be numeric. How did you try to change current character types to numeric and  what was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Flow and Area are still characters. Convert them to numerics, and the error goes away:

```
U <- U %>% 
  mutate(Flow = as.numeric(Flow),
         Area = as.numeric(Area))
# then run the g2 <- U %>% etc. as before
```

[image: plot]